# Passing Styles Based on Parent Component in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a `<Text>` component that is being passed a style so..

`TextFile.js`:

```
<Text style={styles.text}> 
  This is a line of text and this might be a second line 
</Text>
```

`screenFile.js`:

```
<View style={styles.viewContainer}>
    <TextFile style={styles.textWithinContainer}>
</View>
```

`textFiles/styles.js`:

```
text: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'black',
    fontWeight: '400',
}
```

`screenFiles/styles.js`:

```
textWithinContainer: {
    textAlign: 'center',
}
```

`textAlign` within `textWithInContainer` is not being applied. If I add `textAlign: 'center'` to `styles.text` gives me the style I want but it's being used in different screens and I only want it centered in the `screenFile`. I want the styles from `styles.textWithinContainer` to override the styles in `styles.text`. How would I go about this?

Comment: `TextFile` is returning a `Text` element. `textWithinContainer` is a `Text` element within a `View`

Comment: Oh, that's right.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You aren't delegating the styles you pass to `TextFile` to the actual `Text` element in `TextFile`. What you can do is add the styles together by passing an *array* of style objects to apply it:

```
<Text style={[styles.text, props.style]}> 
  This is a line of text and this might be a second line 
</Text>
```

From [the React Native documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style.html):

> You can also pass an array of styles - the last style in the array has precedence, so you can use this to inherit styles.

Thus, if you pass `textAlign` in `textWithContainer`, it'll be applied in the `Text` component, and it can be reused as you wish *without* `textAlign`.

Comment: I'm getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined` when I use `this.props.style`. I then tried `{[styles.text, styles.textWithinContainer]}` within the `TextFile` and as expected, textWithinContainer style is being applied overall. Within `<View>`, do I pass anything to styles here? `<TextFile styles={styles.textWithinContainer} />` ?

Comment: @Dres Are you using a function component? In that case, use `props.style`.

Comment: I am. `const TextFile = ({ text }) => (
  <Text
    accessible={true}
    style={[styles.text, props.style]}
    numberOfLines={2}
    ellipsizeMode={'tail'}
  >
    {text}
  </Text>
);` props.style is giving me `ReferenceError: props is not defined`

Comment: @Dres Okay. `const TextFile = ({ style, text }) => <Text style={[styles.text, style]}></Text>`

Comment: no errors with that one but also no change in styles
`<TextFile styles={styles.textWithinContainer}>` is within a `<View>`. <Text style={[styles.text, styles]}></Text>` is what I'm trying now but no luck. thanks for your help here btw

Comment: @Dres No. `<TextFile style={...}>` -- `style` *not `styles`*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161334/discussion-between-dres-and-li357).

Answer (score 0):

In my initial TextFile, I passed `style` as an argument, and in the `styles` array, just used `style` as the second item in the array.

```
const TextFile = ({ text, style }) => (
   <Text style=([styles.text, style])> {text} </Text>
);
```

Whenever `TextFile` gets used, it will apply any styles being given within that component, and/or default to the initial styles it's being given in `styles.text`.

Thank you @Li357!